# How can reflection help when designing a plugin?

Tags: c#, java, .net, plugins, reflection

I have read that reflection is particularly useful when dealing with plugins.  Could someone kindly highlight the benefits in this particular situation? Both in C# or Java.

Comment: Plugin by definition is an initially unknown source while it may be derived from something known or contain implementations of some known interfaces. Surely some kind of manifest in the plugin can give the names of classes that could be loader and one or another way registered. However class can only be instantiated by name (as string) using reflections. Once the class has been instantiated, further talk with it is possible through some agreed interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"At the highest level of abstraction, the host application must be able to load plug-ins and then communicate with plug-ins to take advantage of their designed services. Both of these tasks can be implemented in different ways depending on a developer’s choice of language and platform. If the choice is C# and .NET, then reflection can be used for loading plug-ins, and interfaces or abstract classes can be used as a means for generic communication."

If you Google some of that you can see the article and read some more on it.

Comment: Well here at least it is said the reflection can be used for loading plugins and interfaces can be used to communicate with them later. True for Java also. This answer uses somewhat very wise and complex language.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just Google it?

In case of .NET you can use an interface to create a basic layout of a plugin. Let's call it 'IPlugIn'. Then you load an Assembly with a class implementing IPlugIn. Now you can look through all the types if one is derived by IPlugIn or define Attributes on the assembly to indicate which class is a plugin.

Comment: Java would not allow to list all classes in the jar, checking maybe some implements the wanted interface.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you do not need to rely on reflection for plugin implementation. I'd suggest using usual interfaces and services. Define some interfaces for your plugins to implement and let them consume the services that will help them integrate with the framework you want to provide them.

Comment: How would you discover the classes that implement the appropriate interfaces?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel Kelley there is a discovery and the first call problems.

Comment: It depends of course, but if his scenario is simple enough he could just reference the other assemblies from his project. He does not provide enough info to speculate on the complexity...